# Search in other column if value not exists

Tags: mysql

I search for a term in the column `synonyms` in my table. In the same table, there is also a column `id`.
Now I would like to search the term in `synonyms` at first. If there is no value in this column, I would like to search in the column `id` for the term.

```
SELECT * FROM `someTable`
WHERE synonyms
LIKE ?
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: `WHERE CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(term, synonims) THEN 1 ELSE FIND_IN_SET(term, id) END`. Both `synonims` and `id` must be either CSV list or single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifnull`.

```
where ifnull(synonyms, id) LIKE ?
```

And if your `If there is no value` means also an empty string, you can use `case`

```
where 
  case 
     when synonyms is null or synonyms='' then id 
     else synonyms 
  end LIKE '%ab%'
```

Comment: I think that "If there is no value" means, for example, the value 'Harley' is no in 'Volvo, BMW, Opel'.

Comment: I mean, if the field is empty